# How to copy the format of locked cells in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365, citrix

after the latest update of the Microsoft 365 package to the version **16.0.16227.20202** (32-bit), I am no longer able to copy paste the format from and to locked cells. In the previous version (16.0.15028.20228) this was possible.
It is possible to copy the format with the dedicated format painter, but not possible to paste it onto other cells which are locked.
The only possibility to copy and paste the format of locked cells, is to unlock the worksheet, copy&paste the format and relock the worksheet. But since there are users that need to do it many more times than me, this is not the right solution for us.

The environment in which we are in is the following:

- Citrix XenApp 2203
- Windows 2016
- Office version 16.0.16227.20202 (32bit; we are using this version since a much need application does only support the 32bit versions of office)

I hope you guys can help me out here.

**EDIT**: The transition to the 64bit-version is currently not possible due to some compatibility issues with an important software that is being used in our company.

Comment: 32-bit support is vanishing quickly. You will need to update your App / Environment to 64-bit.

Comment: That is currently not possible, since the application which needs the 32-bit version of Access is in the process to transition to the 64bit version. This could take some time.

Comment: If that's the only reason, why not just run that software in a VM?

Comment: Any chance you could create a macro to handle the unprotect, copy & paste of formats to their target locations, and then protect sheet again?